# change output format of partial fraction decomposition

Tags: wolfram-alpha

If I ask Wolfram the Partial Fraction Decomposition of, for example,

$$\frac{z^3}{(1-z-z^2)(1-z)(1-2z)}$$

The answer is

$$\frac{z}{z^2 + z - 1} + \frac{2}{z^2 + z - 1} - \frac{1}{z - 1} - \frac{1}{2z - 1}$$

My question is what do I have to type to change the output format? I would like to have answers of the form

$$\frac{1}{1-2z} - \frac{2}{1 - z - z^2} - \frac{z}{1 - z - z^2} + \frac{1}{1 -z}$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this answers my question.